# Cannon.JS make walls solid

Tags: javascript, three.js, cannon.js

I am making a go of three.js and cannon.js, but am stuck with being able to make walls solid, or anything solid that doesn't move and does hold the player back. 
http://www.trepaning.com/3js/SEA3d/elvisCollideWalls.html

Here is the code I have thus far. Any insight appreciated. I prefer figuring stuff out on my own, but this one thing of making walls solid is holding me back at the moment, and I appreciate any info to get me over this hump.

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var initScene;
var MARGIN = 10;
var MARGINSIDE = 0;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth || ( 2 + 2 * MARGINSIDE );
//var WIDTH = window.innerWidth/3 || ( 2 + 2 * MARGINSIDE );
//var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight/3 || ( 2 + 2 * MARGIN );
var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight || ( 2 + 2 * MARGIN );

var SCREEN_WIDTH = WIDTH -2 * MARGINSIDE;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = HEIGHT -2 * MARGIN;

var FAR = 10000;
var DAY = 0;

var stats, camera, scene, renderer;

var mesh, geometry;

var sunLight, pointLight, ambientLight, hemiLight;

var parameters

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var inRender = true;
var inResize = false;

// cannon physics
var world;
var worldScale = 100;
var timeStep = 1/60;
var walls=[], balls=[], ballMeshes=[], boxes=[], boxMeshes=[];
var solidMaterial;
var playerMaterialPhy;

var playerRigid;
var playerPhysicsMesh;

var UNITSIZE = 250
var WALLHEIGHT = UNITSIZE / 3;

var map = [ // 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,], // 0
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,], // 1
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], // 2
           [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1,], // 3
           [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1,], // 4
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], // 5
           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,], // 6
           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,], // 7
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,], // 8
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,], // 9
           ], mapW = map.length, mapH = map[0].length;

// player
var loader;
var player;
var playerMaterial;
var playerMap = { map:undefined, normal:undefined};
var players=[];
var playerName = "LegoElvis";
var scaleFactor = 5;
var velocity = {x : 0, z : 0};

var playerControls = {
    moveForward: false,
    moveBackward: false,
    moveLeft: false,
    moveRight: false,
    bodyOrientation: 0,
    maxSpeed: 275,
    maxReverseSpeed: -275,
    frontAcceleration: 600,
    backAcceleration: 600,
    frontDecceleration: 600,
    angularSpeed: 2.5,
    speed: 0
};

var shadowConfig = {
    Visible: false,
    Near: 750,
    Far: 4000,
    Fov: 75,
    Bias: -0.0002,
    Darkness: 0.5,
    Resolution:1024
};

var playerConfig = {
    name: "",
    loading: 0,
    scale: 1,
    CloneNumber: 30,
    Clone: false
};

var LightConfig = {
    Ambient: 0x554b3b,
    Fog : 0x00283f          
};

var MaterialConfig = {      
    shininess : 0,
    specular: 1,
    normalScaleX: 0,
    normalScaleY: 0,
    bias:0,
    bumpScale: 2,
    metal:false
};

var sky;
var skyCubeNight, skyCubeDay;
var skyShader;

initScene = function () {
    // RENDERER
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { clearColor: LightConfig.Fog, clearAlpha: 1, antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    renderer.setClearColor( LightConfig.Fog, 1 );

    renderer.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById( 'viewport' ).appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

    renderer.gammaInput = true;
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    renderer.physicallyBasedShading = true;

    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( LightConfig.Fog , 1000, FAR );

    // CAMERA
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 2, FAR );
    camera.position.set( 50, 300, 350 );

    // CAMERA CONTROL
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.center.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    controls.keys = [];
    controls.maxPolarAngle = toRad(90);
    controls.userRotateSpeed = 1.8;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 1.6;
    controls.userPanSpeed = 0.8;

    // GROUND
    var mapGround = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/legoElvis.jpg" );
    mapGround.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
    mapGround.repeat.set( 100, 100 );
    mapGround.wrapS = mapGround.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    mapGround.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    mapGround.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { shininess: 10, ambient: 0x444444, color: 0xffffff, specular: 0xffffff, map: mapGround, metal: false } );
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100 );
    var ground = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, groundMaterial );
    ground.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    ground.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
    ground.scale.set( 1000, 1000, 1000 );
    ground.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( ground );

    initLights();

    initPhysics();

    loadSea3dModel();

    stats = new Stats();
    document.getElementById('my-stat').appendChild(stats.domElement);

    // LISTENERS
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp, false );

    // TWEEN
    parameters = { control: 0 };

    animate();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//  LIGHT
//-----------------------------------------------------

function initLights() {


        var sunIntensity = 0.8;
        var pointIntensity = 0.3;
        var pointColor = 0xffffff;
        var skyIntensity = 1;


    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( LightConfig.Ambient );
    scene.add( ambientLight );

    hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.6 );
    hemiLight.color.setHSL( 0.63, 0.05, 0 );
    hemiLight.groundColor.setHex( 0xe4c8a0 );
    hemiLight.position.set( 0, 400, 0 );
    scene.add( hemiLight );

    pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( LightConfig.Moon, pointIntensity, 5000 );
    pointLight.position.set( -1000, 0, -1000 );
    scene.add( pointLight );

    sunLight = new THREE.SpotLight( LightConfig.Sun, sunIntensity, 0, Math.PI/2, 1 );
    sunLight.position.set( 1000, 2000, 1000 );

    sunLight.castShadow = true;
    sunLight.shadowCameraVisible = shadowConfig.Visible;
    sunLight.shadowCameraNear = shadowConfig.Near;
    sunLight.shadowCameraFar = shadowConfig.Far;
    sunLight.shadowCameraFov = shadowConfig.Fov;
    sunLight.shadowBias = shadowConfig.Bias;
    sunLight.shadowDarkness = shadowConfig.Darkness * sunIntensity;

    sunLight.shadowMapWidth = shadowConfig.Resolution;
    sunLight.shadowMapHeight = shadowConfig.Resolution;


    scene.add( sunLight );



}






function enableCascadeShadow() {
    renderer.shadowMapCascade = true;
    sunLight.shadowCascade = true;
    sunLight.shadowCascadeCount = 3;
    sunLight.shadowCascadeNearZ = [ -1.000, 0.995, 0.998 ];
    sunLight.shadowCascadeFarZ  = [  0.995, 0.998, 1.000 ];
    sunLight.shadowCascadeWidth = [ shadowConfig.Resolution, shadowConfig.Resolution, shadowConfig.Resolution ];
    sunLight.shadowCascadeHeight = [ shadowConfig.Resolution, shadowConfig.Resolution, shadowConfig.Resolution ];
}


//-----------------------------------------------------
//  RESIZE
//-----------------------------------------------------

function onWindowResize( event ) {

    inResize = true;
    //document.getElementById("viewport").style.background = '#222222';

    SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth - 2 * MARGINSIDE;
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight - 2 * MARGIN;

    camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//  KEYBOARD
//-----------------------------------------------------

function onKeyDown ( event ) {

    switch ( event.keyCode ) {
        case 38: /*up*/
        case 87: /*W*/
        case 90: /*Z*/  playerControls.moveForward = true; break;

        case 40: /*down*/
        case 83: /*S*/   playerControls.moveBackward = true; break;

        case 37: /*left*/
        case 65: /*A*/
        case 81: /*Q*/    playerControls.moveLeft = true; break;

        case 39: /*right*/
        case 68: /*D*/    playerControls.moveRight = true; break;

    }

}

function onKeyUp ( event ) {

    switch( event.keyCode ) {
        case 38: /*up*/
        case 87: /*W*/ 
        case 90: /*Z*/  playerControls.moveForward = false; break;

        case 40: /*down*/
        case 83: /*S*/  playerControls.moveBackward = false; break;

        case 37: /*left*/
        case 65: /*A*/
        case 81: /*Q*/ playerControls.moveLeft = false; break;

        case 39: /*right*/
        case 68: /*D*/    playerControls.moveRight = false; break;

    }

};

//-----------------------------------------------------
//  SEA3D
//-----------------------------------------------------

function loadSea3dModel() {

    loader = new THREE.SEA3D( false );
    //loader.matrixAutoUpdate = true;
    //loader.invertCamera = true;

    loader.onComplete = function( e ) {
        player = loader.getMesh(playerName);
        player.play("idle");
        player.scale.set( playerConfig.scale*3, playerConfig.scale*3, -playerConfig.scale*3 );
        scene.add( player );
        creatPlayerPhysics();
    };

    //loader.load( 'folder/'+playerName+'.sea' );
    loader.load( 'models/legoElvis.sea' );

}

// PLAYER ANIMATION

function updatePlayer(delta) {

    if (playerControls.moveForward){
        if (player.currentAnimation.name == "idle") player.play("walk");
    } else if (playerControls.moveBackward){
        if (player.currentAnimation.name == "idle") player.play("walk");
    }
    else {
            if(player.currentAnimation.name == "walk") player.play("idle");
    }

    THREE.AnimationHandler.update( delta );
    updatePlayerMove(delta);

}

// PLAYER MOVE

function updatePlayerMove( delta ) {


    playerControls.maxReverseSpeed = -playerControls.maxSpeed;

    if ( playerControls.moveForward )  playerControls.speed = THREE.Math.clamp( playerControls.speed + delta * playerControls.frontAcceleration, playerControls.maxReverseSpeed, playerControls.maxSpeed );
    if ( playerControls.moveBackward ) playerControls.speed = THREE.Math.clamp( playerControls.speed - delta * playerControls.backAcceleration, playerControls.maxReverseSpeed, playerControls.maxSpeed );

    // orientation based on controls
    // (don't just stand while turning)
    var dir = 1;

    if ( playerControls.moveLeft ) {
        playerControls.bodyOrientation += delta * playerControls.angularSpeed;
        playerControls.speed = THREE.Math.clamp( playerControls.speed + dir * delta * playerControls.frontAcceleration, playerControls.maxReverseSpeed, playerControls.maxSpeed );
    }
    if ( playerControls.moveRight ) {
        playerControls.bodyOrientation -= delta * playerControls.angularSpeed;
        playerControls.speed = THREE.Math.clamp( playerControls.speed + dir * delta * playerControls.frontAcceleration, playerControls.maxReverseSpeed, playerControls.maxSpeed );
    }

    // speed decay
    if ( ! ( playerControls.moveForward || playerControls.moveBackward ) ) {
        if ( playerControls.speed > 0 ) {
            var k = exponentialEaseOut( playerControls.speed / playerControls.maxSpeed );
            playerControls.speed = THREE.Math.clamp( playerControls.speed - k * delta * playerControls.frontDecceleration, 0, playerControls.maxSpeed );
        } else {
            var k = exponentialEaseOut( playerControls.speed / playerControls.maxReverseSpeed );
            playerControls.speed = THREE.Math.clamp( playerControls.speed + k * delta * playerControls.backAcceleration, playerControls.maxReverseSpeed, 0 );
        }
    }

    // displacement
    var forwardDelta = playerControls.speed * delta;
    velocity.x = Math.sin( playerControls.bodyOrientation ) * forwardDelta;
    velocity.z = Math.cos( playerControls.bodyOrientation ) * forwardDelta;
    player.position.x += velocity.x;
    player.position.z += velocity.z;
    player.position.y = playerConfig.scale*scaleFactor;

    // steering
    player.rotation.y = playerControls.bodyOrientation;

    if(controls){
        //controls.target.set( player.position.x, player.position.y, player.position.z );
        camera.position.x += velocity.x;
        camera.position.z += velocity.z;
        controls.center.set( player.position.x, player.position.y, player.position.z );
    }

    if(playerRigid){
        //playerRigid.position.set(player.position.x, player.position.y+3, player.position.z ); 
        playerRigid.position.set(player.position.x, player.position.y+80, player.position.z+15 );
        playerRigid.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(0,1,0),player.rotation.y);
    }
};

function exponentialEaseOut( k ) { return k === 1 ? 1 : - Math.pow( 2, - 10 * k ) + 1; };

//-----------------------------------------------------
//  RENDER LOOP
//-----------------------------------------------------

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    if(inRender || inResize){
    //if(isPad)PadTest();
    //updateCamera();
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    if(player!=null)updatePlayer(delta);
    updatePhysics();
    render();
    stats.update();
    }



    inResize = false;

}

function render() {

    TWEEN.update();
    controls.update();



    scene.fog.color.setHSL( 0.63, 0.05, parameters.control );
    renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );

    pointLight.intensity = - parameters.control * 0.5 + 1;
    hemiLight.color.setHSL( 0.63, 0.05, parameters.control )

    sunLight.shadowDarkness = shadowConfig.Darkness * sunLight.intensity;

       renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function tell(s){
    document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = s;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//  PHYSICS
//-----------------------------------------------------

function initPhysics() {

    world = new CANNON.World();


    world.quatNormalizeSkip = 0;
    world.quatNormalizeFast = false;
    var solver = new CANNON.GSSolver();

    world.defaultContactMaterial.contactEquationStiffness = 1e9;
    world.defaultContactMaterial.contactEquationRegularizationTime = 4;

    solver.iterations = 3;
    solver.tolerance = 0.1;

    world.gravity.set(0,-9.82*worldScale,0);//world.gravity.set(0,-9.82,0); // m/sÂ²
    world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadphase();

    // Create a slippery material (friction coefficient = 0.0)
    physicsMaterial = new CANNON.Material("slipperyMaterial");
    solidMaterial = new CANNON.Material("solidMaterial");
    playerMaterialPhy = new CANNON.Material("playerMat");
    var physicsContactMaterial = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(physicsMaterial, physicsMaterial, 0.0, 0.3 );
    var playerContactMaterial = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(playerMaterialPhy, playerMaterialPhy, 0.0, 0.3 );
    var solidContactMaterial = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(solidMaterial, solidMaterial, 0.2, 0.6 );
    world.addContactMaterial(physicsContactMaterial);
    world.addContactMaterial(playerContactMaterial);
    world.addContactMaterial(solidContactMaterial);

    // Create infinie plane
    var groundShape = new CANNON.Plane();
    var groundBody = new CANNON.RigidBody(0,groundShape,physicsMaterial);
    groundBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(1,0,0),-Math.PI/2);
    world.add(groundBody);

    createBoxeObject();
    createBallObject();

}

function creatPlayerPhysics() {
    if(playerPhysicsMesh){
        scene.remove(playerPhysicsMesh);
        playerPhysicsMesh.geometry.dispose();
    }
    if(playerRigid)world.remove(playerRigid);



    //player body 
    var halfExtents = new CANNON.Vec3(0.5*worldScale,playerConfig.scale*80, 0.25*worldScale);
    var playerShape = new CANNON.Box(halfExtents);
    playerRigid = new CANNON.RigidBody(0,playerShape, playerMaterialPhy);
    world.add(playerRigid);
    playerRigid.linearDamping=0.01;
    playerRigid.angularDamping=0.01;

    var boxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(halfExtents.x*2,halfExtents.y*2,halfExtents.z*2);
    playerPhysicsMesh = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry );
    scene.add(playerPhysicsMesh);
    playerPhysicsMesh.useQuaternion = true;
    playerPhysicsMesh.castShadow = false;
    playerPhysicsMesh.receiveShadow = false;
    showPlayerPhysics();
}

function showPlayerPhysics() {
    //if(OptionConfig.ShowPlayerHitBox)playerPhysicsMesh.visible = true;
    //else playerPhysicsMesh.visible = true;
    playerPhysicsMesh.visible = true;
}

function createBallObject() {

    var s = worldScale;
    var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xdddddd } );
    var radius;
    var mass = 4;
    var sphereShape;

    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        radius = (0.2+(Math.random()*0.8))*s;
        sphereShape = new CANNON.Sphere(radius);
        ballGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 32, 32 );
        var sphereBody = new CANNON.RigidBody(mass,sphereShape,physicsMaterial);
        //sphereBody.linearDamping = 0.9;
        var x = ((Math.random()-0.5)*20)*s;
        var y = (1 + (Math.random()-0.5)*1)*s;
        var z = ((Math.random()-0.5)*20)*s;
        sphereBody.position.set(x,y,z); 
        sphereBody.linearDamping=0.03;
        sphereBody.angularDamping=0.03;
        world.add(sphereBody);
        var ballMesh = new THREE.Mesh( ballGeometry, mat );
        scene.add(ballMesh);
        ballMesh.useQuaternion = true;
        ballMesh.castShadow = true;
        ballMesh.receiveShadow = true;
        // add to array
        balls.push(sphereBody);
        ballMeshes.push(ballMesh);
    }
}

function createBoxeObject() {
    var s = worldScale;
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x222222 } );
    // Add boxes
    var sx, xy, xz;
    var halfExtents = new CANNON.Vec3(1*s,1*s,1*s);
    var boxShape = new CANNON.Box(halfExtents);
    var boxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(halfExtents.x*2,halfExtents.y*2,halfExtents.z*2);
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        sx= 0.2+(Math.random()*0.8);
        sy= 0.2+(Math.random()*0.8);
        sz= 0.2+(Math.random()*0.8);
        halfExtents = new CANNON.Vec3(sx*s,sy*s,sz*s);
        boxShape = new CANNON.Box(halfExtents);
        boxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(halfExtents.x*2,halfExtents.y*2,halfExtents.z*2);

        var x = ((Math.random()-0.5)*20)*s;
        var y = (1 + (Math.random()-0.5)*1)*s;
        var z = ((Math.random()-0.5)*20)*s;
        var boxBody = new CANNON.RigidBody(9,boxShape, solidMaterial);
        var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, material );
        world.add(boxBody);
        scene.add(boxMesh);
        boxBody.position.set(x,y,z);
        //boxMesh.position.set(x,y,z);
        boxBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(0,0,0),toRad(Math.random()*360));
        boxMesh.castShadow = true;
        boxMesh.receiveShadow = true;
        boxMesh.useQuaternion = true;
        boxes.push(boxBody);
        boxMeshes.push(boxMesh);
    }




function createObstacle() {



    obstacleMesh = new THREE.CubeGeometry(150, 50, 50)
    obstacleMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x666666 } );
    obstacleObject = new THREE.Mesh(obstacleMesh, obstacleMaterial);
    obstacleObject.position.set(0, 26, 200);
        obstacleObject.castShadow = true;
        obstacleObject.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(obstacleObject);



}

createObstacle();       


function setupScene() {
    var units = mapW;


    // Geometry: walls
    var cube = new THREE.CubeGeometry(UNITSIZE, WALLHEIGHT, UNITSIZE);
    var materials = [
                     new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/legoElvisR.jpg')}), //wall 1
                     new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/legoElvisG.jpg')}), //wall 2
                     ];
    for (var i = 0; i < mapW; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, m = map[i].length; j < m; j++) {
            if (map[i][j]) {
                var wall = new THREE.Mesh(cube, materials[map[i][j]-1]);
                wall.position.x = (i - units/2) * UNITSIZE;
                wall.position.y = WALLHEIGHT/2;
                wall.position.z = (j - units/2) * UNITSIZE;
        wall.castShadow = true;
        wall.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add(wall);
            }
        }
    }

}

        setupScene();


    // Add linked boxes
    var size = 0.5*s;
    var he = new CANNON.Vec3(size,size,size*0.1);
    var boxShape = new CANNON.Box(he);
    var mass = 0;
    var space = 0.1*size;
    var N=5, last;
    var boxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(he.x*2,he.y*2,he.z*2);
    for(var i=0; i<N; i++){
        var boxbody = new CANNON.RigidBody(mass,boxShape, solidMaterial);
        var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, material );
        boxbody.position.set(5*s,((N-i)*(size*2+2*space) + size*2+space)-150,0);

        boxbody.linearDamping=0.01;
        boxbody.angularDamping=0.01;
        boxMesh.useQuaternion = true;
        boxMesh.castShadow = true;
        boxMesh.receiveShadow = true;
        world.add(boxbody);
        scene.add(boxMesh);
        boxes.push(boxbody);
        boxMeshes.push(boxMesh);

        if(i!=0){
            // Connect this body to the last one
            var c1 = new CANNON.PointToPointConstraint(boxbody,new CANNON.Vec3(-size,size+space,0),last,new CANNON.Vec3(-size,-size-space,0));
            var c2 = new CANNON.PointToPointConstraint(boxbody,new CANNON.Vec3(size,size+space,0),last,new CANNON.Vec3(size,-size-space,0));
            world.addConstraint(c1);
            world.addConstraint(c2);
        } else {
            mass=0.3;
        }
        last = boxbody;
    }
}

function updatePhysics() {

   if(!world) return;
    world.step(timeStep);
    // update player mesh test
    if(playerRigid !== undefined){
        playerRigid.position.copy(playerPhysicsMesh.position);
        playerRigid.quaternion.copy(playerPhysicsMesh.quaternion);
    }
    // Update ball positions
    for(var i=0; i<balls.length; i++){
        balls[i].position.copy(ballMeshes[i].position);
        balls[i].quaternion.copy(ballMeshes[i].quaternion);
    }

    // Update box positions
    for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++){
        boxes[i].position.copy(boxMeshes[i].position);
        boxes[i].quaternion.copy(boxMeshes[i].quaternion);
    }

}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//  MATH
//-----------------------------------------------------

function toRad(Value) {
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}


window.onload = initScene;
```

Comment: Seems like you figured it out?

Comment: Not figured out yet, but it is coming along, and when it is, the floodgates will open. Thanks for your hard work.

Comment: Hi, if you set the mass to 0, the object remains "static". I just tried it and I was able to create a building made out of boxes that did not fall apart. You might need to upgrade your libs though.

Answer (score 4):

When you update your physics in `updatePlayerMove`, you set the position of the corresponding Cannon.js body. This body will never have a chance to update its position by itself since you override its position all the time.

Setting the position of bodies like this makes the physics unstable. You'll get large and buggy overlaps. And, of course, the player will be able to walk through walls.

Try controlling the player body via velocity instead. Cannon.js will then provide the response on the player for you, and the physics will become stable:

```
playerRigid.velocity.set(vx,vy,vz);
```

Comment: the player, as is, interacts fine with moveable objects, pushing them around. What I want to achieve is spawn a cube that the player cannot walk through or push. I can do it from an FPS perspective, but not from a 3rd person perspective.

Comment: It is all working as I would like when using a morph animation player character, but not so well when using a skeleton driven character. It'll work out. At least there are solution options available.

Comment: Any way you do it, you'll get unstable physics if you set the position of the physics bodies. If I were you, I'd use velocity based control and rely 100% on Cannon.js. Either do that or implement all collision responses yourself.